# How to SOAP parsing list in android

Tags: android, parsing, soap

I have Text view Java code and soap.

But I want to a ListView. How to parsing soap list in Android.

SOAP 1.1 request and response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<HelloWorldResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <HelloWorldResult>
    <FormModel>
      <Text1>string</Text1>
      <Text2>string</Text2>
      <Text3>string</Text3>
    </FormModel>
    <FormModel>
      <Text1>string</Text1>
      <Text2>string</Text2>
      <Text3>string</Text3>
    </FormModel>
  </HelloWorldResult>
</HelloWorldResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i am connecting to a online web-service.Help me How to parse the xml using Ksoap2.

Parsing soap, Just like only displaying the data in a list.

Mail.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

private static String URL = "http://sygnetinfosol.com/webservice.asmx?WSDL";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Initialize soap request + add parameters
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        


    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    // Make the soap call.
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {

        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.       
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

    if(result != null){
        TextView t = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.resultbox);
        t.setText("SOAP response:\n\n" + result.getProperty(0).toString());
    }

}
}
```

LogCat

```
03-13 06:50:57.077: I/Choreographer(2933): Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 06:50:57.669: I/Choreographer(2933): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 06:50:57.787: I/Choreographer(2933): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 07:16:37.837: E/Trace(3374): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-13 07:16:39.008: I/System.out(3374): MY SOAP RESPONE ISanyType{FormModel=anyType{Text1=12.9174948; Text2=77.5989675; Text3=JayDeva Hospital,Karnataka,Bangalore,India; }; FormModel=anyType{Text1=12.9274529; Text2=77.590597; Text3=9th Block,Central Mall,Jayanagar,Karnataka,Bangalore,India; }; FormModel=anyType{Text1=12.9285212; Text2=77.5834339; Text3=Jayanagar 4th Block,Karnataka,Bangalore,India; }; FormModel=anyType{Text1=12.961085; Text2=77.60469269; Text3=BTM Layout,Richmod Towr,Karnataka,Bangalore,India; }; }
03-13 07:16:39.117: D/dalvikvm(3374): GC_CONCURRENT freed 177K, 11% free 2590K/2908K, paused 80ms+5ms, total 201ms
03-13 07:16:39.438: I/Choreographer(3374): Skipped 347 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 07:16:39.458: D/gralloc_goldfish(3374): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-13 07:16:39.638: I/Choreographer(3374): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 07:16:40.437: I/Choreographer(3374): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: What problem you are getting? are you getting correct response from soap request?

Comment: @Sangeetha your getting xml as the response of sosap request and you want to parse the same and display the items in listview??

Comment: @Bhavesh yes but through soap

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes I want to parse the same and display the items in list

Comment: can u post the xml response of the soap request. just print the response in logcat and paste the same here

Comment: @Raghunandan I posted LogCat also, You will see

Comment: System.out.println("MY SOAP RESPONE IS"+result.getProperty(0).toString(). This will print response in logcat and you can post the same here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below link

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/30/android-lists-v-accessing-and-consuming-a-soap-web-service-ii/

It is suitable code try this.

Answer (score 0):

you can refere below link, it explains how to deal with complex object Array with ksoap:

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html

In this example he has explained how to get list of objects from soap response,

After that you can pass that list to your listview if you want to show your data in listview

Answer (score 0):

Try use "androidHttptransport.responseDump" because it gives xml formate and use Dom Parser to parse responsedump and put in listView as you want.

```
         String response = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();

            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));

            doc = db.parse(is);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            // Node hh=doc.getElementsByTagName("hhCompany").item(0).;

            org.w3c.dom.Element ee = doc.getDocumentElement();
```